# When I copy the contents of a script in a Runbook and save it, it's empty is this due to the size limit?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I have a script which contains quite a few characters. When I paste this script in to Azure Automation and save as a draft or even publish, the script is always empty. The script is in total 2mb.

Is this due to the size of the script, or is this the stream limit?

What is the exact size limit of a script, and what do they mean with a stream limit?

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-automation-service-limits.md

I got the stream limit from here, but there is nothing about the size of a Runbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the runbook size is 1mb max